# Upgrade Neo4j 2.3 to 3.4 - Unable to access jarfile 2.x-config-migrator.jar

Tags: neo4j, upgrade

I'm attempting to upgrade my neo4j 2.3 to 3.4 on MacOS so I can use apoc. Both old and new versions are together in my hard drive root folder at paths: `/neo4j/2.3`  `/neo4j/3.4`

Both versions have the config files set to allow upgrade and 3.4 has never been run. The old graph.db file has been copied over to 3.4. The next step for upgrade is to run the 2.x upgrade file in Terminal:

```
java -jar 2.x-config-migrator.jar /neo4j/2.3 /neo4j/3.4
```

I'm getting the error:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile 2.x-config-migrator.jar

Anyone know why? - I'm starting from my home directory: `pwd` gives me: `/Users/Damon`
Directions I'm following are here: 
[Neo4j Upgrade Instructions](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/)

Comment: I think you'll need to run this from the `tools` directory where the 2.x-config-migrator.jar is located.

Comment: Thanks InverseFalcon it worked!..  And thanks for your recent work on the apoc procedures - I can't wait to use them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2.x-config-migrator.jar file requires a path to the directory it's in, in this case it was:

```
java -jar bin/tools/2.x-config-migrator.jar /neo4j/2.3 /neo4j/3.4
```